# AEM Serving dynamic content (JSPs) from /etc/designs

Tags: aem, sling

I would like to implement an extensible templating mechanism in AEM, so as to permit component users to control markup for individual projects (designs) without modifying the components' pre-defined JSPs.

I have extended the `<cq:include>` tag to permit this, by passing a template name, which is then retrieved from the current design, falling back to the default markup when an override does not exist in the design:
`<ct:template name="listNav/prev" />`

This should load the jsp script from [1], unless the location does not exist, defaulting to [2]:

1. `/etc/designs/projectName/component_templates/listNav/prev.jsp`
2. `/etc/designs/component_templates/listNav/prev.jsp`

When using the extended tag, I'm receiving the exception (yes, the file exists):

`Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Could not find script /etc/designs/component_templates/listNav/prev.jsp`

This all works when the component_templates is under `/apps`.  Is there any way to make this work?  Is there a better approach?  I'd prefer to keep the `component_templates` with the designs, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea to put application script to etc. They  should be under /apps.

But I think it could work, if you add /etc path to the "Resource Search Path" of this service:
system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl

Comment: Thanks @nerd.  I've heard apprehension about scripts in `/etc` before, but never had an explanation as to why.  Can you give any details as to why it would be a bad idea to store JSP scripts under `/etc/designs`?

I tried your suggestion to add `/etc` or `/etc/designs` to the "Resource Search Path" of the JCR Resource Resolver Factory configuration, but I continued to receive the same ServletException as before.  Any other suggestions?

I guess I'll have to deal with the files under `/apps` for now.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose between different "designs" within the advanced page properties tab! afaik you should use this mechanism to declare different designts i.e. stylesheets etc. to your pages and of cause you don't need to modify anything at the jsp's to switch between different styles if implemented properly.

[image]

Have a look at this:

[Adobe AEM Designs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/the-basics/designer.html)